# Problem with GSList (GLib)

Tags: c, programming-languages, glib

HI,

I'm trying to use GSList from glib.h but I'm having problems when filling the list with char * elements.

Here's the code:

```
GSList * res = NULL;
char * nombre;

while (...) {
 nombre = sqlite3_column_text(resultado, 1);
     res = g_slist_append (res, nombre);
}   

printf("number of elements: %i\n", g_slist_length(res));
printf("last element: %s\n", g_slist_last(res)->data);
```

When I print the number of elemnts, I see the list is not empty. But when I print the last element, It doesn't show anything...

What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your last column text is empty?

Comment: no no, It has a string on it. Before, I tested it with a printf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list will only retain the pointer value. If the memory the pointer is pointing at is later overwritten, you will have problems.

The solution could be to [duplicate](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup) the string before storing it:

```
res = g_list_append(res, g_strdup(nombre));
```

This will store pointers to new strings, stored in freshly-allocated memory, different for each string. Of course, you need to clean this up afterwards by calling `g_free()` on each of the stored pointers, or your program will leak memory:

```
g_list_free_full(res, g_free);
```

This calls the standard `g_free()` function on each data pointer, before freeing the list itself.

Comment: @mccrank: Glad it helped. Feel free to accept the answer, too.