# How to use DEFCFUN with a pointer to a foreign C function?

Tags: common-lisp, glib, cffi

I am using CFFI to interact with a library that uses GLib. The [`g_list_free_full()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html#g-list-free-full) function in GLib has the signature:

```c
void
g_list_free_full (GList *list,
                  GDestroyNotify free_func);
```

I will need to call this function from Lisp because I am working with some functions in which I need to create `GList` objects, so I also need to free them afterwards. In C, I would do it like this (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5949438/2954547)):

```c
g_list_free_full(res, g_free);
```

So far my Lisp bindings look like this:

```lisp
(asdf:load-system :cffi)

(defpackage :test-glib-bindings
  (:use :common-lisp :cffi))

(in-package :test-glib-bindings)

(define-foreign-library libglib
  (:unix (:or "libglib-2.0.so.0" "libglib-2.0.so")))

(use-foreign-library libglib)

(defctype gint :int)
(defctype gboolean :boolean)
(defctype gpointer :pointer)

(defcfun "g_free" :void
  (mem gpointer))

(defcfun "g_list_free_full" :void
  (lst gpointer)
  (fun :pointer))
```

But I'm not sure if my `defcfun` signature is correct for `g_list_free_full()`, and I'm not sure how to call it correctly from Lisp. My naive guess is to write:

```lisp
(g-list-free-full my-glist (get-callback 'g-free))
```

but it's hard to tell if this is the right way (or best way) to do things. I'm also not an experienced C programmer, and I don't know if this will technically work but cause some kind of other problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if `get-callback` is defined for functions not declared with `defcallback`. This is not tested, but you probably only need to resolve the `"g_free"` symbol in the library to its pointer, and pass this value as an argument.

You can call `fs-pointer-or-lose` or `foreign-symbol-ptr` to get the pointer to the native `g_free` function; instead of calling `(get-callback 'g-free)`, you write:

```
(fs-pointer-or-loose "g_free")
```

Alternatively, at the cost of doing a trip back to Lisp, you can use `defcallback` and `callback`.
For that, you need define a Lisp `free` function as a callback, and have it call the native function.

```
(defcfun (g-free "g_free") :void (mem gpointer))

(defcallback free :void ((mem gpointer))
  (g-free mem))
```

Then you would pass the pointer to the callback with `callback`.

```
(g-list-free-full my-glist (callback free))
```

Comment: Thanks, `foreign-symbol-pointer` seems like a reasonable starting point, so I'll try that. However I don't see `fs-pointer-or-lose` anywhere in the CFFI docs, has the function been renamed to something else?

Comment: I found it by looking at the source code, I am not sure right now if the symbol is exported.